# Gas fireplace insert won't stick to marble fireplace

Tags: heating

I have a marble fireplace and 2 years ago my gas fire insert fell out, I tried to stick it back in with heat resistant silicone but it fell back out. It is a metal gas insert any suggestions on what to use to seal it back onto the marble.

Comment: Without a picture it is hard to tell exactly what you need to do, but a lot of these are held in with set screws or mounting brackets, I have not seen any held in with caulk

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, I would attempt to locate the instruction manual for your unit. You may still have it somewhere in a junk drawer or similar, but almost just as easy, you should be able to look it up online or by contacting the manufacturer.

Many of these inserts are mounted by a series of fasteners from the structural interior of the where the unit is to be mounted, either directly to the gas insert, or to a bracket that will support, attach and secure the insert mechanical. To date, in the US, I cannot imagine any that are specified to be installed with any kind of adhesive. This just wouldn't make sense for servicing.

IF you unit is literally falling out of the wall, there is a very good chance for damage to the gas supply line and/or electrical ignitor and thermostat system. I would personally not feel comfortable with anything short of a licensed and certified tech to come and repair/install my unit.

If gas supply, electrical and HVAC are out of your area of expertise, please see a professional.